# Displaying 3 products on WooCommerce cart, even if not bought

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

On a WP WooCommerce, been trying to bypass the `[woocommerce_shop]` and sending visitors directly to `[woocommerce_cart]` and displaying there the 3 options they have and they'll be able to select quantity and proceed to checkout. 
e.g:

```
Ticket for adults     [2]▼▲   
Tickets for minors    [1]▼▲
Tickets for seniors   [0]▼▲

|CHECKOUT|
```

Tried several plugins without sucess and editing `woocommerce>templates>cart>cart.php` but couldn't find the filter that adds only items with quantities >0  and not a list of desired products.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have recently did the same work for one of my clients so you can follow the steps given below.

#### Some background

There are no easy ways to do this because of mainly two reasons:

1. You can't add products with Zero quantity in to cart. There are many places where this is checked and handling all of them would be pain in butt.
2. WooCommerce does not support adding multiple products into cart at once. There is an [PR open](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/17855) for that but there is not a fix timeline of when it will be accepted and released.

**Note 1**: This is very specific to the current version of WooCommerce and in case of any breaking changes to Templates or `WC_Form_Handler` class this method will break. While I have tried to stay compatible with core, this still uses some hacks.

**Note 2**: This assumes that you are using default `cart.php` template with no modifications in `shop_table` especially in `table rows` where `woocommerce_cart_item_*` are displayed. If you are using a modified version please update the `table rows` structure below as per your setup.

**Note 3**: Major caveat is that you need at least one item added to cart for this to work otherwise `cart-empty.php` template is loaded instead of `cart.php` so our hook `woocommerce_cart_contents` won't fire. On the other hand you can simply modify `cart.php completely which will give you better control. I shall add another answer detailing that as well.

---

#### Actual code

Everything goes inside `functions.php` located at `wp-contents\themes\your-theme-folder\`

*This is an example code. You will need to update the code below to suit your setup. Check comments inside the code.*

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_contents', 'mm_woocommerce_cart_contents');

/**
 * Cart Additional Products List Fragment
 */
function mm_woocommerce_cart_contents(){

// @Note: Modify WP_Query arguments below to get the products you are looking for
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => wp_list_pluck(WC()->cart->get_cart(), 'product_id'),
);

// Set the query
$products = new WP_Query( $args );

//Starting output buffering
ob_start();

// Standard loop
if ( $products->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
        $_product = wc_get_product( $post );

        // Making sure that In Stock or Backorder Allowed products are not 
        // shown so there are no out-of-stock errors when updating cart
        if (! ( $_product->is_in_stock() || $_product->backorders_allowed() ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        ?>

        <!-- @Note: Modify HTML structure below this line in case you are using modified cart.php in your theme -->
        <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $_product ) ); ?>">

            <td class="product-name">
                <?php
                if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title() ) . '&nbsp;';
                else
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s </a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $_product->get_title() ) );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-quantity">
                <?php

                if( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                    $max_value = 1;
                } else {
                    $max_value = $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity();
                }

                $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                    'input_name'  => "mm_additional_products[{$_product->id}]",
                    'input_value' => '0',
                    'max_value'   => $max_value,
                    'min_value'   => '0'
                ), $_product );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-price">
                <?php
                echo WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-subtotal">
                <?php
                echo '--';
                ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-remove">
                <?php
                echo '--';
                ?>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;

// Echoing HTML from the loop above.
echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

**We have just added the *view* part. Now let's add data processing.**

```
/*
* Multi Add to Cart Functions
*
* Modified version of
* https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/
*/

function mm_add_to_cart_additional_products( $url = false ) {
    // Make sure WC is installed, and mm_additional_products query arg exists.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Form_Handler' ) || empty( $_REQUEST['mm_additional_products'] ) )  {
        return;
    }

    // Remove WooCommerce's hook, as it's useless (doesn't handle multiple products).
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

    // Handle products with zero quantity from the array and assign
    $product_ids = array_map( 'intval', $_REQUEST['mm_additional_products'] );
    $product_ids = array_filter( $product_ids, function( $v ){
        return $v > 0;
    });

    $count       = count( $product_ids );
    $number      = 0;

    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id => $quantity ) { //$id_and_quantity

        $_REQUEST['quantity'] = $quantity;

        if ( ++$number === $count ) {
            // Ok, final item, let's send it back to woocommerce's add_to_cart_action method for handling.
            $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $product_id;

            return WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action( $url );
        }

        $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $product_id ) );
        $was_added_to_cart = false;
        $adding_to_cart    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        // If a there isn't any Product for this ID let's skip the cycle
        if ( ! $adding_to_cart ) {
            continue;
        }

        $add_to_cart_handler = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', $adding_to_cart->get_type(), $adding_to_cart );

        // Variable product handling
        if ( 'variable' === $add_to_cart_handler ) {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_variable', $product_id );

        // Grouped Products
        } elseif ( 'grouped' === $add_to_cart_handler ) {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_grouped', $product_id );

        // Custom Handler
        } elseif ( has_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler ) ){
            do_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler_' . $add_to_cart_handler, $url );

        // Simple Products
        } else {
            woo_hack_invoke_private_method( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_handler_simple', $product_id );
        }
    }
}

// Fire before the WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action callback.
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'mm_add_to_cart_additional_products', 15 );


/**
 * Invoke class private method
 *
 * @since   0.1.0
 *
 * @param   string $class_name
 * @param   string $methodName
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
function woo_hack_invoke_private_method( $class_name, $methodName ) {
    if ( version_compare( phpversion(), '5.3', '<' ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'PHP version does not support ReflectionClass::setAccessible()', __LINE__ );
    }

    $args = func_get_args();
    unset( $args[0], $args[1] );
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass( $class_name );
    $method = $reflection->getMethod( $methodName );
    $method->setAccessible( true );

    $args = array_merge( array( $class_name ), $args );
    return call_user_func_array( array( $method, 'invoke' ), $args );
}
```

---

Places to know more on how to add multiple products in to cart:

- https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/17477
- https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/17855

Comment: thanks for the answer; didn't work, tried adding the snippets to functions.php with no luck. I've read the links you gave, allows adding multiple prodcuts at once, but couldnt figure out how to show zero quantity on cart, has to be a workaround. Does any other platform support this?

Comment: @Tecnoduque This answer will work when you have at least one product in cart and you want to show other products so user can purchase directly. I'll be adding another answer shortly which will show how to modify `cart.php` and have all products shown even when cart is empty.